# Distribute yearly measure over months with predefired percent values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a yearly goal for number of graduates. I want to distribute this yearly number to monthly level using predefined percent numbers.

[image: Goals table]

I would like to get

- jan = 1.7% * 292 = 4.96
- feb = 1.4% * 292 = 4.01
  etc...

The problem is that yearly number of graduates has date of 2021-01-01 and relation to date table, so it will only work for the first month. (Other months are blank). I cannot change the date relation because I have other goals in the same table that use month

Here are my measures

```
Graduates goal = CALCULATE( SUM(value), Measure = 'Graduates goal')
Goal% = CALCULATE( SUM(value), Measure = 'Graduates%)
Montly graduate target = CALCULATE( [Graduates goal] * [Goal%])
```

I have tried using ALL(Dates[Month]) ALL(Dates[Year]) but I cannot get past that month level restriction in yearly goal.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able to solve this with crossfilter something like this

```
Montly graduate target = CALCULATE([Graduates goal], CROSSFILTER( Goals, Dates, None), YEAR(Pvm) = YEAR(TODAY())) * Goal%
```